# Creating a list from data frame of value greater than a specific value

Tags: python, list, dataframe, indexing

I have a question on how to create a list of values that are greater than a specific value in a given data frame variable.

```
       a.     b.     c.
1.    100     57     23   
2.     99     56     23
3.    100     56     22
4.    101     57     23
...
300.   99     50     23 
301.   99     51     29
302.  101     57     22
```

Create a list of all values where a > 100.

I am able to index, but not a list since all the values are boolean:

```
Greater_100 = df['a']>100
```

How do I turn this into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 200, (10, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
list_a_more_than_hundred = df[df.a>100]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped! However, when I try to combine two categories, i.e., a > 100 and b < 57 in a manner df[list_a_more_than_hunderd & list_b_less_than_57], I get an error. How would I fix that?

Comment: list_a_more_than_hundred = df[(df.a>100) & (df.b<57)]

Answer (score 0):

Only `df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a']` or `df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a'].tolist()` is sufficient.

Selecting the rows from column `a` where value is > 100.

```
>>> df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a']
4      101
302    101
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>>
>>> type(df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Converting the above Series into list.

```
>>> l = df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a'].tolist()
>>> l
[101, 101]
>>>
>>> type(l)
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Let's look at the above code in more detail.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> arr = [[100, 57, 23], [99, 56, 23],
... [100, 56, 20], [101, 57, 23], [99, 50, 23],
... [99, 51, 29], [101, 57, 22]]
>>>
>>> columns = [ch for ch in 'abc']
>>> indices = [str(n) for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 300, 301, 302]]
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=indices, columns=columns)
>>> df
     a   b   c
1    100  57  23
2     99  56  23
3    100  56  20
4    101  57  23
300   99  50  23
301   99  51  29
302  101  57  22
>>>
>>> df['a'] > 100
1      False
2      False
3      False
4       True
300    False
301    False
302     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
>>>
>>> arr2 = df.loc[:,'a']
>>> arr2
1      100
2       99
3      100
4      101
300     99
301     99
302    101
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>>
>>> arr2 = df[df['a'] > 100]
>>> arr2
     a   b   c
4    101  57  23
302  101  57  22
>>>
>>> arr3 = df[df['a'] > 100].loc[:, 'a']
>>> arr3
4      101
302    101
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>>
>>> l = arr3.tolist()
>>> l
[101, 101]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter your dataframe for rows where `a > 100`, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
res_df = df.query('a > 100')
```

This also works for multiple conditions:

```
res_df = df.query('a > 100 & b < 57')
```

If you wish to extract a list of values from these rows, you can use use NumPy, e.g.

```
res_lst = df.query('a > 100 & b < 57').values.ravel().tolist()
```